# Installing GlusterFS latest version?

Tags: glusterfs

I've only limited experience with linux package management and I'm struggling on what should be a simple package install of glusterfs.

First I enable the repo

```
wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/LATEST/RHEL/glusterfs-epel.repo
```

Then I install with:

```
yum -y install glusterfs-server
```

However I believe there is some issue with the latest package references:

```
yum install glusterfs
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.7/LATEST/EPEL.repo/epel-latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.7/LATEST/EPEL.repo/epel-latest/noarch/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
No package glusterfs available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I've tried editing the glusterfs-epel.repo to override the based urls but I've not been able to install a working package.

I'm on a fresh Amazon AMI:

```
cat /etc/*elease
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2015.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2015.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2015.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2015.09
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed via enabling EPEL correctly

http://website-humblec.rhcloud.com/gluster-3-7-upgrade-in-el-systems/

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Centos, you can also do:

```
yum install centos-release-gluster37
```

Or a newer release.

Answer (score -1):

The latest version of GlusterFS as of 2020/10/14 :-

```sh
vatsa@vatsa-VirtualBox:~$ glusterfs --version
glusterfs 2020.10.14
Repository revision: git://git.gluster.org/glusterfs.git
Copyright (c) 2006-2016 Red Hat, Inc. <https://www.gluster.org/>
GlusterFS comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
It is licensed to you under your choice of the GNU Lesser
General Public License, version 3 or any later version (LGPLv3
or later), or the GNU General Public License, version 2 (GPLv2),
in all cases as published by the Free Software Foundation.
```

// I have the source code version not the package.